# Will_paginate inside POST form with nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, nested-attributes, will-paginate

I have Two models: Self-assessment and Score, where Self-assesment `has_many :scores` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for :scores`. New self assessment form may have up to 60 nested scores. What I would like to do is implement pagination to those nested attributes fields inside a form.

I tried to implement it with no luck.

controller

```
def new
  @self_assessment = SelfAssessment.new
  @scores = @self_assessment.scores.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10, :total_entries=> @self_assessment.scores.size)
end
```

view

```
<%= form_for @self_assessment do |f| %>
    <h2>At home...</h2>
    <% Category.where(at_home: true).each do |category| %>
        <h3><%= category.title %></h3>
        <% Act.where(category_id: category.id).each do |act| %>
            <%= f.fields_for :scores, Score.new do |builder| %>
                <%= builder.hidden_field :self_assessment_id, value: @self_assessment.id %>
                <%= builder.select(:rank, scales_for_select(act), prompt: "-Select-") %>
                <%= act.name %><br>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>

    <h2>At work...</h2>
    <% Category.where(at_work: true).each do |category| %>
        <h3><%= category.title %></h3>
        <% Act.where(category_id: category.id).each do |act| %>
            <%= f.fields_for :scores, Score.new do |builder| %>
                <%= builder.hidden_field :self_assessment_id, value: @self_assessment.id %>
                <%= builder.select(:rank, scales_for_select(act), prompt: "-Select-") %>
                <%= act.name %><br>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <%= will_paginate @scores, :params => { :method => :post } %>
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
```

Comment: hi how did you achieve this please post your code